# How to switch to simple app switcher

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently when we press alt+tab it brings one app to foreground and brings next app if we keep pressing tab.

1. Is there anyway to bring simple app switcher like in Ubuntu or Mint and then use arrow key to move to next and previous app instead of pressing tab.
2. If I decide to modify the package which is responsible for switching apps, where can I start? Like what is the name of the package?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend starting here: [gala-elementary-alt-tab-switcher](https://github.com/p0pye/gala-elementary-alt-tab-switcher)

Being on github you can easily access the code to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely an upgrade. But it prevented application menu from popping up on pressing Super + Space. Also arrow keys are not working. I'll tinker around with this. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but the following commands will open Slingshot with Super only and not Super-Space. I haven't tried it with the alt-tab-switcher, so I can't say for sure whether it will resolve your issue. But could be worth a shot. gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key "'Super_L'"gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "'wingpanel --toggle-indicator=app-launcher'"

Comment: If you're able to customize it, would you mind sharing your work? I'd like to try it.

Comment: Sure, I'll probably fork a branch in git if I am able to do it or I'll submit a pull request. So far, I am looking at code and its not very intuitive. Hardcoded constants everywhere with minimal to no comments. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @SeanPatterson My Slingshot is mapped to `Super + S` and it doesn't pop up after installing the switcher either.

Comment: @Fultie Did you try running the command above? I'm curious is after install the alt-tab-switcher that changing the gsettings will get it back to the way we need it.

Comment: @SeanPatterson Apparently it got fixed after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the Gala Elementary OS's Window Manager. 
https://github.com/elementary/gala/

You might want to look around for previous discussions, there have been plenty. On https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/ and in the issue queue for example.